# How to change python interpreter on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I have python3.8 version installed on my Mac and is detected as the python interpreter for vscode. However, I also installed python3.6 which is the version I am trying to use in vscode for my project. I know the python interpreter path for python3.8 is under `/usr/local/bin/python3.8`, but I want to switch this to python3.6. I have checked that python3.6 exists under the same directory so I tried to switch my python interpreter in vscode by typing `C-Shift-P` and then typing in the path `/usr/local/bin/python3.6`, but vscode states that it is invalid.

How exactly do you switch python versions/interpreter in vscode on a MacOS?

I need to install python3.6 because I need to use tensorflow version 1.9.x.

Answer (score 0):

I just verified this right now on Mac OSX. The other answer is incorrect. If you want to remove a Python Interpreter from the list, choose shift + command + p. Then choose “Python: Select Interpreter”. This will show that it is now the active interpreter appear on the bottom right of the VSCode Window. Now launch the terminal within vscode. Remove the interpret from your system using the shell (e.g. rm [path-to-interpreter]. Close VSCode and then reopen VSCode. And now return back to “Python: Select Interpreter” and you will see the Interpreter no longer appears there. I just verified this right now.

Answer (score -1):

As [detailed in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter):

Press `cmd`-`shift`-`P` then type `python: select interpreter` and press `return` then click the circular arrow in the top right (`refresh interpreter list`). If your python interpreter is not shown then click `Enter interpreter path...` then click `Find...` and a file select dialog will appear from which you can navigate to the appropriate interpreter and select it.

Note that the you may run into problems as [the Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) does not support python versions below `3.7`, because [it is no longer supported](https://devguide.python.org/versions/#versions). You may be able to [use an old version of the extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19596#issuecomment-1201502093) if you need debugger support for `3.7`.

Comment: On mac it's `CMD+shift+P` not `ctrl`

Comment: When I click `Find...` it opens the select dialog, and I am unsure how to navigate to `/usr/local/bin/` because I have been unable to find the `/usr` directory on the MacOS without using a terminal

Comment: @Jeff Boker Have you adjusted the version of python extension to  `2022.8.*`?

Comment: If you click `cmd`-`shift`-`g` when in the file select dialog you should be able to enter a path, i.e. `/usr`, and press `return` then hunt down the appropriate file from there.